# Reproducing a table containing images and multi-line text in a cell

Tags: tables, graphics, pdftex, multirow

I'd like to be able to reproduce the table attached as an image to this post in Latex. The original table comes from my PhD thesis which was written in Microsoft Word 5.0 on a Mac in the early 1990s. As such I've long since lost the original files (disk crashes over a twenty year period took care of that) and in any case I don't think I'd be able to read the original files into the latest version of Word even if I had them.

Thanks in advance,

Bruce

[image: Table from my PhD thesis I want to reproduce in Latex/Tex]

Comment: Are you looking for reproducing the table only? Or you need the graphs as well? (+1) for choosing Latex over Microsoft Word.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide some starter document with `\documentclass{...}` and `\begin{document}...\end{document}`

Comment: @CroCo, I would like to reproduce the whole layout with the multiple lines of text in column 1 and the figures in columns 2 and 3. However, the figures would be created in another program and added as vector graphic files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,
               preview]{standalone}
    \usepackage{graphicx}

    \usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
    \usepackage{array,booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{m{5cm}cc}
    \toprule
\textbf{Exercise 1}
\begin{itemize}
\item Instruction 1.
\item Instruction 2.
\item Instruction 3.
\end{itemize}
& \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,
                   valign=m, margin=.5em]{example-image} 
& \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,
                   valign=m, margin=.5em]{example-image} \\ 
    \midrule
%%
\textbf{Exercise 2}
\begin{itemize}
\item Instruction 1.
\item Instruction 2.
\item Instruction 3.
\end{itemize}
& \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,
                   valign=m, margin=.5em]{example-image} 
& \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,
                   valign=m, margin=.5em]{example-image}    \\ 
    \midrule
\textbf{Exercise 3}
\begin{itemize}
\item TEST.
\item TEST.
\end{itemize}
& \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,
                   valign=m, margin=.5em]{example-image} 
& \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,
                   valign=m, margin=.5em]{example-image} \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Since you didn't provide MWE, I left to you tu put in mine desired text and images.

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I need. Thanks @Zarko

Comment: accepted as suggested. Sorry about the MWE. I did try but couldn't get anything to work. I'm very new to LaTeX at this stage.